# Como criar um diretório em Python dentro de um servidor?

Tags: python, servidor, diretório, mkdir

Usando a função *mkdir* é possivel criar um arquivo em qualquer diretório dentro das pastas do computador:

```
Import os
diretorio = "C:\\Users\\CRIACAO 2\\Desktop\\teste"
os.mkdir(diretorio)
```

Porém quando tento cria-la dentro do endereço de um servidor, o programa não é capaz de encontrar o caminho indicado:

```
Import os
diretorio = "\\servidor\ARABRINDES 1TB\Artes"
os.mkdir(diretorio)
```

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado: '\servidor\ARABRINDES 1TB\Artes\andrei'

Como posso resolver esse problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu problema é que você está usando uma contrabarra só, e caminhos para servidor começam com duas contrabarras `\\`...

Explicando melhor, o Python interpreta strings que tem contrabarras de forma especial. Por exemplo, `'\t'` é o tab, `'\n'` é a quebra de linha e `'\\'` é uma barra só!

Você pode ver que esse é o caso através da mensagem de erro:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] O sistema não pode encontrar o caminho especificado: 
'\servidor\ARABRINDES 1TB\Artes\andrei'
```

Para resolver, use quatro barras, ou seja, duas para cada barra:

```
diretorio = "\\\\servidor\\ARABRINDES 1TB\\Artes"
```

Ou melhor ainda, use *raw strings* sempre que for escrever um caminho:

```
diretorio = r"\\servidor\ARABRINDES 1TB\Artes"
```

Colocando esse `r` antes da string faz com que o python não processe caracteres especiais dentro dela. Ela sai exatamente como está escrita!

Leia a documentação aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals

Comment: Muito obrigado! O erro era exatamente isso e consegui resolve-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema parecido, esse erro aconteceu porque está executando o comando para um **caminho relativo** e não um **caminho absoluto**. O correto seria passar por parâmetro todo o caminho do servidor.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Não é o caso, o caminho `\\servidor\ARABRINDES 1TB\Artes` é absoluto - inclui o nome do servidor, o compartilhamento e todo o caminho para chegar na pasta.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção, acabei confundindo o problema que tive.